# Works on simulator but "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil ..." on device

Tags: ios, swift

I am learning from Stanford swift course and I have a serious problem.

My problem is that when I run my application in emulator it works perfectly fine, but when I try to run it on my physical iPhone it crashes with error message "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value".

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController
{
@IBOutlet weak var display: UILabel!

var userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber = false

@IBAction func appendDigit(sender: UIButton)

{
    let digit = sender.currentTitle!

        if userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber
        {
            display.text = display.text! + digit
        }
            else
        {
            display.text = digit
            userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber = true
        }

}

@IBAction func operate(sender: UIButton)
{
    let operation = sender.currentTitle!

    if userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber
    {
        enter()
    }
    switch operation
    {
    case "×": performOperation(multiplay)
    case "÷": performOperation(divide)
    case "+": performOperation(add)
    case "−": performOperation(minus)
        default: break
    }
}

func performOperation(operation: (Double, Double)  -> Double)
{
    if operandStack.count >= 2 {
        displayValue = operation(operandStack.removeLast(), operandStack.removeLast())
        enter()
    }
}

func multiplay(op1: Double, op2: Double) -> Double {
    return op1 * op2
}
func divide(op1: Double, op2: Double) -> Double {
    return op1 / op2
}
func add(op1: Double, op2: Double) -> Double {
    return op1 + op2
}
func minus(op1: Double, op2: Double) -> Double {
    return op1 - op2
}

var operandStack = Array<Double>()

@IBAction func enter()
{
    userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber = false
    operandStack.append(displayValue)
    print("operandStack = \(operandStack)")

}
var displayValue: Double
{
    get
    {
        return NSNumberFormatter().numberFromString(display.text!)!.doubleValue
    }
    set
    {
        display.text = "\(newValue)"
        userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber = false
    }
 }

 }
```

this error message is:

```
libswiftCore.dylib`function signature specialization <Arg[0] = Exploded, Arg[1] = Exploded, Arg[2] = Dead, Arg[3] = Dead> of Swift._fatalErrorMessage (Swift.StaticString, Swift.StaticString, Swift.StaticString, Swift.UInt) -> ():
0x1001dc740 <+0>:   stp    x29, x30, [sp, #-16]!
0x1001dc744 <+4>:   mov    x29, sp
0x1001dc748 <+8>:   sub    sp, sp, #16
0x1001dc74c <+12>:  and    w8, w2, #0x1
0x1001dc750 <+16>:  tbnz   w8, #0, 0x1001dc770       ; <+48>
0x1001dc754 <+20>:  tbnz   x1, #63, 0x1001dc7b4      ; <+116>
0x1001dc758 <+24>:  add    x1, x0, x1
0x1001dc75c <+28>:  mov    x2, x3
0x1001dc760 <+32>:  mov    x3, x4
0x1001dc764 <+36>:  mov    x4, x5
0x1001dc768 <+40>:  bl     0x10021edd0               ; function signature specialization <Arg[0] = Exploded, Arg[1] = Exploded> of Swift.(_fatalErrorMessage (Swift.StaticString, Swift.StaticString, Swift.StaticString, Swift.UInt) -> ()).(closure #2)
->  0x1001dc76c <+44>:  brk    #0x1           There it is!!!!
0x1001dc770 <+48>:  str    xzr, [sp, #8]
0x1001dc774 <+52>:  cmp    x0, w0, uxtw
0x1001dc778 <+56>:  b.ne   0x1001dc94c               ; <+524>
0x1001dc77c <+60>:  lsr    w8, w0, #11
0x1001dc780 <+64>:  cmp    w8, #26
0x1001dc784 <+68>:  b.hi   0x1001dc7d8               ; <+152>
0x1001dc788 <+72>:  cmp    w0, #128
0x1001dc78c <+76>:  b.lo   0x1001dc808               ; <+200>
0x1001dc790 <+80>:  orr    w8, wzr, #0x80
0x1001dc794 <+84>:  bfxil  x8, x0, #0, #6
0x1001dc798 <+88>:  cmp    w0, #2048
0x1001dc79c <+92>:  b.hs   0x1001dc83c               ; <+252>
0x1001dc7a0 <+96>:  movz   x10, #0
0x1001dc7a4 <+100>: movz   x11, #0
0x1001dc7a8 <+104>: lsr    w9, w0, #6
0x1001dc7ac <+108>: orr    w9, w9, #0xffffffc0
0x1001dc7b0 <+112>: b      0x1001dc86c               ; <+300>
0x1001dc7b4 <+116>: adr    x0, #808224               ; "fatal error"
0x1001dc7b8 <+120>: nop    
0x1001dc7bc <+124>: adr    x3, #808724               ; "UnsafeBufferPointer with negative count"
0x1001dc7c0 <+128>: nop    
0x1001dc7c4 <+132>: movz   w1, #0xb
0x1001dc7c8 <+136>: orr    w2, wzr, #0x2
0x1001dc7cc <+140>: movz   w4, #0x27
0x1001dc7d0 <+144>: orr    w5, wzr, #0x2
0x1001dc7d4 <+148>: bl     0x1001dc740               ; <+0>
0x1001dc7d8 <+152>: cmp    w0, #14, lsl #12
0x1001dc7dc <+156>: b.lo   0x1001dc818               ; <+216>
0x1001dc7e0 <+160>: cmp    w0, #272, lsl #12
0x1001dc7e4 <+164>: b.hs   0x1001dc900               ; <+448>
0x1001dc7e8 <+168>: orr    w8, wzr, #0x80
0x1001dc7ec <+172>: bfxil  x8, x0, #0, #6
0x1001dc7f0 <+176>: orr    w9, wzr, #0xffffff80
0x1001dc7f4 <+180>: bfxil  w9, w0, #6, #6
0x1001dc7f8 <+184>: lsr    w10, w0, #16
0x1001dc7fc <+188>: cbnz   w10, 0x1001dc924          ; <+484>
0x1001dc800 <+192>: lsr    w10, w0, #12
0x1001dc804 <+196>: b      0x1001dc848               ; <+264>
0x1001dc808 <+200>: movz   x9, #0
0x1001dc80c <+204>: movz   x11, #0
0x1001dc810 <+208>: mov    x8, x0
0x1001dc814 <+212>: b      0x1001dc89c               ; <+348>
0x1001dc818 <+216>: adr    x0, #808124               ; "fatal error"
0x1001dc81c <+220>: nop    
0x1001dc820 <+224>: adr    x3, #811328               ; "high- and low-surrogate code points are not valid Unicode scalar values"
0x1001dc824 <+228>: nop    
0x1001dc828 <+232>: movz   w1, #0xb
0x1001dc82c <+236>: orr    w2, wzr, #0x2
0x1001dc830 <+240>: movz   w4, #0x47
0x1001dc834 <+244>: orr    w5, wzr, #0x2
0x1001dc838 <+248>: bl     0x1001dc740               ; <+0>
0x1001dc83c <+252>: lsr    w10, w0, #12
0x1001dc840 <+256>: orr    w9, wzr, #0xffffff80
0x1001dc844 <+260>: bfxil  w9, w0, #6, #6
0x1001dc848 <+264>: movz   x12, #0
0x1001dc84c <+268>: movz   x11, #0
0x1001dc850 <+272>: orr    w10, w10, #0xffffffe0
0x1001dc854 <+276>: and    x10, x10, #0xff
0x1001dc858 <+280>: lsl    x13, x12, #3
0x1001dc85c <+284>: lsl    x10, x10, x13
0x1001dc860 <+288>: orr    x11, x10, x11
0x1001dc864 <+292>: str    x11, [sp, #8]
0x1001dc868 <+296>: add    x10, x12, #1
0x1001dc86c <+300>: orr    w12, wzr, #0x8
0x1001dc870 <+304>: umulh  x12, x10, x12
0x1001dc874 <+308>: cmp    xzr, x12
0x1001dc878 <+312>: b.ne   0x1001dc94c               ; <+524>
0x1001dc87c <+316>: lsl    x12, x10, #3
0x1001dc880 <+320>: cmp    x12, #63
0x1001dc884 <+324>: b.hi   0x1001dc8dc               ; <+412>
0x1001dc888 <+328>: and    x9, x9, #0xff
0x1001dc88c <+332>: lsl    x9, x9, x12
0x1001dc890 <+336>: orr    x11, x9, x11
0x1001dc894 <+340>: str    x11, [sp, #8]
0x1001dc898 <+344>: add    x9, x10, #1
0x1001dc89c <+348>: orr    w10, wzr, #0x8
0x1001dc8a0 <+352>: umulh  x10, x9, x10
0x1001dc8a4 <+356>: cmp    xzr, x10
0x1001dc8a8 <+360>: b.ne   0x1001dc94c               ; <+524>
0x1001dc8ac <+364>: lsl    x10, x9, #3
0x1001dc8b0 <+368>: cmp    x10, #64
0x1001dc8b4 <+372>: b.hs   0x1001dc8dc               ; <+412>
0x1001dc8b8 <+376>: and    x8, x8, #0xff
0x1001dc8bc <+380>: lsl    x8, x8, x10
0x1001dc8c0 <+384>: orr    x8, x8, x11
0x1001dc8c4 <+388>: str    x8, [sp, #8]
0x1001dc8c8 <+392>: add    x8, sp, #8
0x1001dc8cc <+396>: add    x8, x9, x8
0x1001dc8d0 <+400>: add    x1, x8, #1
0x1001dc8d4 <+404>: add    x0, sp, #8
0x1001dc8d8 <+408>: b      0x1001dc75c               ; <+28>
0x1001dc8dc <+412>: adr    x0, #807928               ; "fatal error"
0x1001dc8e0 <+416>: nop    
0x1001dc8e4 <+420>: adr    x3, #808332               ; "shift amount is larger than type size in bits"
0x1001dc8e8 <+424>: nop    
0x1001dc8ec <+428>: movz   w1, #0xb
0x1001dc8f0 <+432>: orr    w2, wzr, #0x2
0x1001dc8f4 <+436>: movz   w4, #0x2d
0x1001dc8f8 <+440>: orr    w5, wzr, #0x2
0x1001dc8fc <+444>: bl     0x1001dc740               ; <+0>
0x1001dc900 <+448>: adr    x0, #807892               ; "fatal error"
0x1001dc904 <+452>: nop    
0x1001dc908 <+456>: adr    x3, #811176               ; "value is outside of Unicode codespace"
0x1001dc90c <+460>: nop    
0x1001dc910 <+464>: movz   w1, #0xb
0x1001dc914 <+468>: orr    w2, wzr, #0x2
0x1001dc918 <+472>: movz   w4, #0x25
0x1001dc91c <+476>: orr    w5, wzr, #0x2
0x1001dc920 <+480>: bl     0x1001dc740               ; <+0>
0x1001dc924 <+484>: lsr    w10, w0, #18
0x1001dc928 <+488>: orr    w11, w10, #0xf0
0x1001dc92c <+492>: cmp    w11, w11, uxtb
0x1001dc930 <+496>: b.ne   0x1001dc94c               ; <+524>
0x1001dc934 <+500>: orr    w10, wzr, #0xffffff80
0x1001dc938 <+504>: bfxil  w10, w0, #12, #6
0x1001dc93c <+508>: and    x11, x11, #0xff
0x1001dc940 <+512>: str    x11, [sp, #8]
0x1001dc944 <+516>: orr    w12, wzr, #0x1
0x1001dc948 <+520>: b      0x1001dc854               ; <+276>
0x1001dc94c <+524>: brk    #0x1
```

Comment: which line of your code does that error come from?

Comment: Actually this happens only when I am trying to perform a calculation (my app is a calculator) and the error message isn't assigned to any line of code. It appears in sth called "specialised fatal error message "

Comment: You can add breakpoints to your code to find out what method fails. Knowing where this problem occurs is essential for understanding how to fix it.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann could you please take a look at this line of code? It is in the error message.

Comment: I don't see where `newValue` is declared in your view controller.  Could a missing variable be the source of all your problems?

Comment: Yeah that was it! Thanks a lot! @MichaelDautermann ! Now everything is working perfectly!